# Is there a way to optimize code for pairing the elements in a list and generate count of pairs

Tags: python

i want to optimize my code for following question

/*
A company sells dumbbells in pairs. These are weights for exercising. They receive a shipment of dumbbells weighing anywhere from 1 unit up to a certain maximum.

A pair can only be sold if their weights are sufficiently close: no greater than 1 unit difference.

Given an inventory of various weights, determine the maximum number of pairs the company can sell.

For example, if there are 2 dumbbells of weight 1, 4 of weight 2, 3 of weight 3 and 1 of weight 4, (arr = [2,4,3,1])

they can be paired as [1,1], [2,2], [2,2], [3,3], [3,4] for a total of 5 pairs.

i-th element is the number of dumbbells with a weight of i+1.
*/

For example :

if arr  = [3,5,4,3]
number of pairs will be 7 as shown below:
initial array is to be converted to  [3(1's),5(2's),4(3's),3(4's)] i.e [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]

Now we need to make pairs like this [1,1][1,2][2,2][2,2][3,3][3,3][4,4] remaining last 4 is left as it is single .so total number of pairs is 7

following is my solution for the same :

```
def taskOfPairing(arr):
    
    n = len(arr)
    count = 0
    newList = []
    
    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        newList += [i + 1]*j
    print(newList) 
    count1 = 0
    k = 1
    newList.sort()
    n1 = len(newList)
    l=0
    r=0
    while r<n1:
        if newList[r]-newList[l] < k:
            count1 += 1
            newList.pop(l)
            newList.pop(r)
            n1 = len(newList)
            l=0
            r=0
            if len(newList) == 1:
                break
    return count1



arr= [3,5,4,3]
print(taskOfPairing(arr))
```

**output = 7**

however my output works but only when there is small numbers in list like arr = [3,5,4,3] or [2,4,3,1]

If i try putting large numbers in list for example , arr = [100000,200000,300000,400000] my code will not work and will cause a lot of delay in execution , can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong in this code .My apologies to stack overflow for asking naive questions .

Comment: I don't see any benchmarks in your question. What specifically are you trying to optimize? If you're looking for general review and critique of working code, you should consider asking at [codereview.se] SE instead.

Comment: hi brian , i am trying to optimize my code as i am using two for loops hence when the array will be larger it will take  more time in execution. I do not want to use this code . Any help will be welcome

Comment: @DiwakarSHARMA every code you would use to create this would fundamentally need the same number of iterations, there is no way around that. You cannot escape a linear relationship between the input size and the execution time here. There is no free lunch

Comment: ok thanks guys , i thought i might be doing it wrong or slow

Comment: I mean, there are ways to make your code simpler, and not create unnecessary intermediate lists, like just do a nested loop, `for i, x in enumerate(arr, 1): for _ in range(x): mewlist.append(i)`. Of course, the *time/space complexity* would be the same. But probably marginally more performant and IMO more clear

Comment: OP's code is more O(N^2) and not linear due to list adding. Using a single list comprehension ````[i+1 for i,x in enumerate(arr) for y in range(x)]````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one loop, because python allowes to do something like that:

```py
arr= [3,5,4,3]
newList = []
for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        newList += [i + 1]*j
print(newList)
```

It also removes some unnecessary things that can cause more time to execute, but I don't really know if it will be some much faster, maybe on a very big `list`

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

## TESTS

I wrote some tests for your code and the difference is very high, I have to tell. The code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint, seed

def ts():
    return datetime.now().timestamp()

def diff(st, en):
    print(f'{round((en - st) * 1000, 3)} ms')

N = 4
arr= [randint(1, 10**N) for _ in range(10**N)]

"""
    My solution
"""
st = ts()

newList = []
for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        newList += [i + 1]*j

en = ts()
diff(st, en)


"""
    Your solution
"""
st = ts()

count = 0
newList = []
for j in (arr):
        count += 1
        b = [int(count) for i in range(j)]
        newList += b
        
en = ts()
diff(st, en)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
234.294 ms
2861.242 ms
```

My solution is like `12` times faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [3,5,4,3]

out = []
for i, e in enumerate(arr, 1):
    out += [i] * e
out
```